# Is there a way to unlock to Home screen without swiping up?

Tags: iphone

In short, I would like my iPhone X to go to the Home screen (first page of apps) immediately after Face ID unlocks my phone, without having to swipe up from the Notifications screen.

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible without any touch, but you can make it just a touch instead of a swipe by creating an Assistive Touch gesture for swiping up, then triggering this gesture instead of swiping.