# What is the fastest way to unlock iPhone X to the homescreen? (rather than double tap, Face ID, swipe up)

Tags: iphone, unlock, ios, face-id

Needless to say every 0.1 second counts, I want to stay in the flow as much as possible.

Current method of unlocking iPhone X <strike>pisses me off</strike> is really annoying - it requires 3 independent interactions.

Related: [Is there a way to unlock to Home screen without swiping up?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306473/is-there-a-way-to-unlock-to-home-screen-without-swiping-up)

Answer (score 2):

You can raise the phone or press the side-button and then swipe up. You do not have to wait for Face ID to complete in between.

This is much faster compared to double-tap, wait for Face ID and swipe.

There's no way currently to access the home screen faster, for example without having to swipe up.